# GET javascript net::ERR_ABORTED 404 in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

In my laravel application, I'm using translation through localization javascript. When I'm using it offline the only localhost it's working fine but on the server, it is giving me `GET https://my_url.com/js/lang.js net:: ERR_ABORTED 404` and file is accessed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If an HTTP error like 404 is thrown, it means your file can't be found.

Comment: but I open the code by `ctrl+u` and when I clicked on that js file link then it is opening.